# Authenticated user is lost in web api owin middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jwt, autofac, owin-middleware

I'm using `owin middleware` and `Jwt Bearer Aurhentication` alongside `Autofac` that help my `Webapi` to handle requests.

`JwtBearerAuthentication` middleware works fine and set `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` to `true` and it persist until pipeline reaches to `webapi` `middleware` , in my `webapi` authenticated user is lost

order of middlewares are as follows:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{

    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    #region Autofac config

    var container = AutofacWebapiConfig.Initialize(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    #endregion
    #region RoutConfig

    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    #endregion

    //Register middlewares
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new MyJwtAuthenticationOptions());
    app.Use<RedirectUnAuthenticateRequestsMiddleware>();
    app.Use<ReadBodyMiddleware>();
    app.UseWebApi(config); //in this middleware authenticated user is lost

}
```

Here is my WebApiConfig class:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Owin auth
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter("Signature"));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy =
IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
        // Web API routes
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Services.Insert(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), 0,
         new SimpleModelBinderProvider(typeof(DocumentModel), new FromFormDataBinding()));
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Have you any idea?

```
Update:
```

Inside my owin middleware after authentication middleware, `IsAuthenticated` is set to true

```
  public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
      var isAuth=context.Request.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;//It is true as expected.
                await Next.Invoke(context);
                return;
}
```

but when it reaches to my controller

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;//It is false.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was from this line in `WebApiConfig` class;

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
```

When i commented,issue disappeared and authenticated user persisted in webapi.